How to count mismatches between two rows, column by column
I am trying to count the number of mismatches in values between two rows (two samples), going column by column in R. I want to only count mismatches that don't include an NA. Here is some example data:
Sample1  0 1 1 2 NA 2 1 1
Sample1b 1 1 1 2 1  1 1 1
Sample2  2 2 1 0 0 NA 0 0
Sample2b 2 2 1 1 0 NA 0 0

Id like to do this in groups of two rows (comparing sample 1 to sample 1b, and then sample 2 to 2b, and so forth). In this example, Sample 1vsSample 1b would have 2/7 mismatches and sample 2 vs 2b would have just 1/7 (the NA comparisons are removed from the denominator).
I've tried using an apply over columns, comparing each line, but haven't gotten that far.

An approach using pivot_longer, then creating the group and filter by NA, finally summarize the result and paste the output.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-V1) %>% 
  group_by(grp = sub("(.*\\d+).*", "\\1", V1), name) %>% 
  filter(!any(is.na(value))) %>% 
  summarize(mismatch = value[1] != value[2]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  summarize(mismatch = paste0(sum(mismatch), "/", n()), .by = grp)

output
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  grp     mismatch
  <chr>   <chr>
1 Sample1 2/7
2 Sample2 1/7

Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("Sample1", "Sample1b", "Sample2", "Sample2b"
), V2 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), V3 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), V4 = c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L), V5 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 1L), V6 = c(NA, 1L, 0L, 0L),
    V7 = c(2L, 1L, NA, NA), V8 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V9 = c(1L,
    1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))


It might be easier to apply the mean for the last summarize to get the mismatch percentage

@ryanzom Yep, but depends what OP intends. At that point the work is done, since we have all required variables, they can output whatever they want.

Sorry, I had not looked at the output properly. I understand what you going for

You can try
rev(
  stack(
    lapply(
      split(df, sub("\\D+$", "", row.names(df))),
      \(x) mean(Reduce(`!=`, as.data.frame(na.omit(t(x)))))
    )
  )
)

which gives
      ind    values
1 Sample1 0.2857143
2 Sample2 0.1428571

data
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
    V3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 1L), V5 = c(NA,
    1L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(2L, 1L, NA, NA), V7 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
    ), V8 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sample1",
"Sample1b", "Sample2", "Sample2b"))

> df
         V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
Sample1   0  1  1  2 NA  2  1  1
Sample1b  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1
Sample2   2  2  1  0  0 NA  0  0
Sample2b  2  2  1  1  0 NA  0  0


I would do the obvious
vapply(split(df0, sub("\\D+$", "", row.names(df0))), 
       \(x) mean(x[1L, ] != x[2L, ], na.rm=TRUE), 
       numeric(1L)) |> MASS::fractions()

which, obviously, assumes that there are always exactly two rows per sample group (1,2,3,...,n, n \in natural numbers).
giving
Sample1 Sample2 
    2/7     1/7 


Note
Data used
df0 = structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                     V3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V4 = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 1L), 
                     V5 = c(NA,1L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(2L, 1L, NA, NA), 
                     V7 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), V8 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sample1", "Sample1b", "Sample2", "Sample2b"))


Another solution using rowSums
library(dplyr)
dat |> 
  mutate(group = gsub("\\D+$", "", V1)) |> 
  mutate(.by = group, across(V2:V9, \(x) first(x), .names="{.col}.")) |> 
  mutate(mismatch = rowSums(across(V2:V9) != across(V2.:V9.), na.rm=TRUE),
         denom = rowSums(across(V2.:V9., \(x) !is.na(x)), na.rm=TRUE),
         result = as.character(MASS::fractions(mismatch / denom))) |> 
  filter(result != 0) |> 
  select(group, result)

# output
    group result
1 Sample1    2/7
2 Sample2    1/7

data
dat <- read.table(text="Sample1  0 1 1 2 NA 2 1 1
Sample1b 1 1 1 2 1  1 1 1
Sample2  2 2 1 0 0 NA 0 0
Sample2b 2 2 1 1 0 NA 0 0")

